# clickhouse-client cannot login after enable listen host 0.0.0.0

Tags: clickhouse

After installed the ClickHouse on Ubuntu 18.04.2 in Hyper-V VM, I use clickhouse-client inside the VM to connect, it works fine.

I used the browser in Host PC to open http://127.27.16.11:8123, it shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. Then I edit the /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml and uncomment the 0.0.0.0 and restart the clickhouse-server. I refresh the browser and it shows OK status.

However, when I use clickhouse-client inside the VM to connect server again, it prompts Connection refused. Is there any way to enable both local and remote connection?

Also tried to enable both IPv4 and IPv6
::
0.0.0.0

```
ubuntu02:/$ clickhouse-client
ClickHouse client version 19.11.3.11 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 19.11.3 revision 54423.

ubuntu02 :) quit
Bye.

ubuntu02:/$ sudo vi /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
[sudo] password for panco:

##uncomment
<listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>

ubuntu02:/$ ping ubuntu02
PING ubuntu02 (172.27.16.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ubuntu02 (172.27.16.11): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.015 ms
64 bytes from ubuntu02 (172.27.16.11): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
^C
--- ubuntu02 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3039ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.015/0.033/0.040/0.012 ms

ubuntu02:/$ sudo service clickhouse-server restart

ubuntu02:/$ clickhouse-client
ClickHouse client version 19.11.3.11 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)
```

Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

found the answer, I was too focus on those IP that I used is IPv4, indeed, Ubuntu enable IPv6 by default installation. It just simple uncomment this line

```
<listen_host>::</listen_host>
```

The problem is solved. Thanks Slesh for your kindly respond anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```sh
clickhouse-client -h 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to specify few host to listen. Try this configuration:

```
<!-- Listen specified host. use :: (wildcard IPv6 address), if you want to accept connections both with IPv4 and IPv6 from everywhere. -->
<listen_host>::</listen_host>
<!-- Default values - try listen localhost on ipv4 and ipv6: -->
<listen_host>::1</listen_host>
<listen_host>127.0.0.1</listen_host>
```

Comment: I tried to add two lines of listen_host,  0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 and this doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you try config that I provided?

Comment: tired, still the same. even uncomment all four ::, ::1, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 listen_host, still the same.

Comment: @Panco Please share if you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Need to know the port of clickhouse

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

And connect externally IP.
ex.

```
clickhouse-client -h 1.12.123.45 --port 9020 -u default --password my_strong_pass
```