# AWS firewall preferences

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, clickhouse

I have problem with connecting my AWS instance:

1) I created security group with the following preferences:

```
- Type-All traffic; Protocol-All; Port Range-All; Source-0.0.0.0/0
- Type-Custom TCP Rule; Protocol-TCP; Port Range-9000; Source-z.y.x.t/p (obtained via `ip addr show`)
```

2) I launched clickhouse both on z.y.x.t/p and AWS end entered `clickhouse-client --host aws_ip_address` and got the following error: `DB::NetException: Connection refused`

3) I added security rule for 9001 port access from the same ip

4) Installed Anaconda on AWS and launched jupyter notebook on port 9001

5) Tried to connect via browser and again there was no success.

6) After that I tried connect via ssh to the notebook and it connected

Tell me please how can I resolve error with database and connect it from local computer.

Comment: by default CH listens only localhost https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254685/11644308

Comment: It seems to me that this response helps to solve this problem with local connection, while I get troubles with remote. Moreover everything works with Alibaba and only AWS does not work

Comment: it could be firewall enabled in Linux. Check iptables.

Comment: iptables -S returns: 1) -P INPUT ACCEPT 2) -P FORWARD ACCEPT 3) -P OUTPUT ACCEPT 4) -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT. Looks like it should accept inbound connection on port 9000

Comment: Thank you very much, eventually you first answer worked!